# How to hide the navigation bar?

Tags: nokia-lumia-630, lumia-denim

I tried to follow the [instructions](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/phones-and-hardware/use-the-navigation-bar), but on settings is only possible to change the color of the navigation bar. How do I hide it? It's not possible to do this in Lumia 630?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature seems to be not availiable on the Lumia 630 for some reason - I think it has something to do with the screen resolution but have not found a definitive answer to why it is not working.
http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Lumia/How-to-hide-the-on-screen-bottom-navigation-bar-Advice-Please/td-p/2777674